# How to upload image and createview

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I don't understand how to add this image object on view.
please help me.

**models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    image = models.ImageField(default='post.jpg', upload_to='image')

    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

what i do for the image field is valid. 
I want to be able to upload an image file using CreateView and a LoginRequiredMixin but I can't get it working - it seems the form doesn't bind any file data after choosing a file. Here's the current content of the view

**views**

```
 class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
       model = Post
       fields = ['title', 'content','image']

       def form_valid(self, form):
           form.instance.author = self.request.user

           return super().form_valid(form)
```

any think i do jast show the default photo. i do not understand how to handle this.I try my best i think.

**post_form.html**

```
 {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
 {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
 {% block content %}
   <div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Blog Post</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" 
        type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
       </form>
    </div>
   {% endblock content %}
```

**home.html**

```
  {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
  {% block content %}
     {% for post in posts %}
       <article class="media content-section">
      <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ 
       post.author.profile.image.url }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }} 
          </small>
        </div>
        <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}"> 
         {{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ post.image.url }}">
      </div>
     </article>
     {% endfor %}
   {% endblock content %}
```

**command line**

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax 
is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\Arvan\\Desktop\\django_project\\medi
a\\<MultiValueDict: {}>'
[07/Dec/2018 04:04:39] "GET /media/%3CMultiValueDict%3A%20%7B%7D%3E HTTP/1.1" 
500 80871
```

Comment: Can you show the template for the create post form? The template you have shown seems to be for the list posts page.

Comment: hello Will Keeling,
add the create post template...

Comment: You're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `<form>`. See Whodini's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your current form_valid method in your view try:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect'))
```

and in your template make sure your form has the following:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

key being the enctype for submitting files.